# Is "to choose" right in this sentence?

Tags: difference

I've got a sentence from a friend:

> There has been an increasing number of people **to choose** to use cell
>   phones in daily life.

Is the sentence grammatically right?

Why is it "to choose" instead of "choosing"?

Comment: I'd say you have it reversed: in this particular sentence, people would normally say *choosing*, not *to choose*. *To choose* is fine in many contexts, but not this one. It isn't strictly wrong here, but it's unusual and would normally not be used.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks. Can I have more details about it?

Comment: It's simply not idiomatic here. It's a slightly convoluted way of saying something that's more simply expressed by *choosing* (or *who choose*). The use of the infinitive doesn't flow well in this context.

Comment: @JasonBassford ok :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To choose** and **choosing** would mean different things.

Your sentence implies that someone/group can choose from an increasing number of people to make use of cell phones. It carries the sense of **to choose from...**. So the head of a telecoms company might tell his staff that there are now more people to choose (from) to use cell phones. Although this scenario is unlikely, it's quite grammatical.

**Choosing** would mean that the people themselves would be making the choice rather than having it made for them by a third party.

Comment: So can I assume that in most situations, "to choose" is wrong?

Comment: It's not idiomatic and could well be misunderstood.